# cant manage showing products from categories in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
// This block grabs the whole list for viewing
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$sql = mysql_query("select * from categories,products_cat,products where categories.id=products_cat.cat_id and products.id=products_cat.prod_id and categories=$cat");
$catCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $prod_list .= "category ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> <br />";
    }

?>
```

and i have those three tables:
1) products table:
id , product_name,price,category,subcategory

2) categories table:
id,cat

3) products_cat table:
cat_id, prod_id

i cant manage to show the products from certain category that the user will input from command line, cat=x , it only gives me this error:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/perzul12/public_html/beta/show.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/perzul12/public_html/beta/show.php on line 7
```

Please help me ! it is my only money resource for the month and i cant manage to do it !

Comment: Please help us first by using `mysqli_()` instead of `mysql_()`

Comment: instead of mysql_num_rows i should use mysqli_num_rows ??

Comment: Nah, take a look here http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

The work here is not in the deprecated `mysql_` functions. Rather, you have not returned a valid result set. Try this.

```
"select products_cat.products, categories.* 
from categories,
left join products_cat on products_cat.cat_id=products.id
where categories={$cat}"
```